# Which processors can run CIL

Tags: cil

Which processors are capable of running [Common Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)(CIL), formerly known as Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL)? Clearly any machine that can run Microsoft Windows with .net qualifies as well as machines targeted by the [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) project.

It would appear that the [.NET Micro Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework) has the ability to target other processors not covered by the above, but it is not clear to me that it uses CIL.

Does anyone have a list of which processors are capable of running a program in CIL and or interpreting C# directly (as the .NET Micro Framework appears to do)?

*EDIT* to clarify, I understand that CLI is not executed directly on the metal but rather by a a runtime engine. So for this question any processor with a runtime engine that executes CIL qualifies.

Comment: Your question doesn’t really make sense. Either you’re asking what processors actually use CIL as their machine instruction code, in which case, the answer is of course “none” — or you’re asking what processors could theoretically execute a CLR, in which case obviously the answer is “all of them, except for those that are so limited that they can’t really execute an arbitrary program”.

Answer (score 3):

None. There is no processor that runs CIL - CIL is to my knowledge ALWAYS translated to another form of machine code.

I think there is a CIL processor "floating around" are research project, but so far not seen in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Micro Framework doesn't allow processors to interpret CIL directly. It is simply an even more lightweight interpreter that runs on embedded hardware instead of requiring a full PC architecture. It's like .NET Compact Framework but with a smaller footprint. To look at the architectures that this supports:

[.NET Micro Framework Hardware](http://www.microsoft.com/netmf/hardware/default.mspx)

Comment: Technically it is an interpreter and not a compiler. http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~gpollice/cs544-f05/CourseNotes/maps/Class1/Compilervs.Interpreter.html

You can see details on what the .NET framework is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

There is a compiler that turns your C# into CIL which then is used by the .NET interpreter to actually do work.

Comment: The CLR compiles CIL to machine code and executes it, i.e. it is a compiler and not an interpreter. See Futamura projections: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation#Futamura_projections

Comment: Jon, taking an intermediate language and executing it (by making it machine code since that's all the processor understands) *IS* an interpreter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)). The difference is, does it happen on the fly during execution or at the point the developer hits compile waaay before the program runs. You're splitting hairs, because both definitions have blurred as computing as evolved. For years VM based languages have been considered interpreted languages (Java, C# -- even Lisp). To try and argue that interpreters are also compilers is moot.

Comment: There is no point in arguing for the sake of argument. Waste of time and I'm sure we all have better things to do.

Comment: Sorry, the .NET Micro Framework *does not* compile CIL to machine code before execution so it is an interpreter and not a compiler. The .NET Compact Framework does JIT compile and .NET Micro source code includes a JIT compiler but it is disabled (!). My bad. http://netmf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/12176#39401

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, [TomTom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285465/tomtom) is right.
They call it Intermediate for a reason... it is between the programmer's language and the processor's language.
An interesting thought, though - having a processor that runs CIL code.

Answer (score 0):

I found two **research** processors that execute CIL natively much like the [JOP](http://www.jopdesign.com/) does for Java Bytecode:

[SCIL](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4488013&contentType=Conference+Publications&sortType%3Dasc_p_Sequence%26filter%3DAND%28p_IS_Number%3A4487950%29%26rowsPerPage%3D75) According to the paper it supports a subset of CIL, so the some portions of CIL will have to be emulated in subroutines. Honestly though the processor and paper do not look well put together.

[DSP Core for Hardware Based CIL Machine](http://ws.elance.com/file/DSP_Core_for_Hardware_Based_CIL_Machine.pdf?crypted=Y3R4JTNEcG9ydGZvbGlvJTI2ZmlkJTNEMjQzODU1MzglMjZyaWQlM0QtMSUyNnBpZCUzRDIzMDE0OTA=) This one looks more legitimate, however its designed with a very specific purpose in mind (DSP on a mobile phone).

Realize that these cores are meant for use with FPGAs. Sadly neither of them provided source code or bitfiles, so you will have to request more information from the authors if you actually want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

On the [.NET Micro Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework) page it mentions a CLR which is what is running the CIL.

> It includes a small version of the .NET CLR...

The [supported platforms on mono-project.com](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/) list a few architectures.

Though be careful to test it before investing too much time.
The only guaranteed targets are those bundled with the Xamarin product.
In the past mono was missing floating point support on some ARM architectures which since has been added.